# my Admin Controller in codeigniter have one issue

Tags: codeigniter

I have one `admin_controller`. I am accessing that `controller` form login. So I set form action login. Again I tried to login I want to change the form action to `Admin_controller/login`. How can I solve this issue?

```
 $referrerUrl1 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 if($referrerUrl1=="/MallFinder/admin/" || $referrerUrl1=="MallFinder/admin" ||  $referrerUrl1=="MallFinder/index.php/admin")
 {
    $route['default_controller'] = "Admin_controller";
 }
 else
 {
    $route['default_controller'] = "Welcome";
 }
 $route['404_override'] = '';
 $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: try to get your .htaccess working and remove index.php from your url @Anju

Comment: I am new in codeigniter.So plz explain in detailed .Actually its working fine but i need to change the form action at first time when login

Comment: While I have never tried it, I don't think I would recommend dynamically setting your default controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Starters. You can Read [Codeigniter 3.x Login with Form Validation -Boiler plate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084899/codeigniter-3-x-login-with-form-validation-boiler-plate)

It has all what you need , form validation, querying database, session etc. But for Security you need to read [Codeigniter Security Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html) and [Codeigniter Encryption Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html)