# Codeigniter 3.x Login with Form Validation -Boiler plate

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3

I have been reading couple of questions here from different newbies about Login and validation in codeigniter, some have mixed JavaScript and J-query. Codeigniter itself provide a robust form validation along with custom error setting support. I have decided to share with you the easiest way to kickstart in codeigniter with login boilerplate which I have created and I am sharing it with you. It has

**Controller** 
Login

**Model**: Login_model

**Views**: Login and success

And basic configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1**

Download Codeigniter 3.x from [Official Website](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/downloads.html)

**Step-2**

Extract in a folder in your localhost root. (htdocs in xampp and www in wamp)

**Step-3. Configuration**

Open the folder you have extracted the codeigniter in go to 
application->config->autoload.php. Go to line 55 and autoload these two libraries

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Go to line 67 and load two helpers

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
```

Save the file and now go the application->config->config.php

Set Base URL on line 19 as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/folder_name/';
```

On line 31 remove the index.php from value and change it to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

on line 49 set uri_protocol from AUTO to REQUEST_URI

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

on line 229 set an encryption key

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '!@#$%^&*()ASDFGHJKL:ZXCVBNM<>QWERTYUIOP';
// I recommend you create a hash and place it here
```

Save the file

**Step-4 .htaccess**

On the root of codeigniter installation folder create an .htaccess file write following in it and save

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Step-5. Create Database**

Open your phpmyadmin or mysql terminal create a database , create a table users in it , you can use following query

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('pending','approved') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Step -6. Connecting Database to Codeigniter**

Go to application->config->database.php. Assuming its a fresh install and you haven't created any environments. Go to line 52 and change the four lines to

```
$db['default']['username'] = 'username'; // will be root if you have xampp
$db['default']['password'] = 'password'; // will be empty if you haven't set
$db['default']['database'] = 'your_database_name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; // changed from mysql to mysqli
```

**Step-7. The View**

[image]

[Source Code](https://github.com/malikmudassar/Boiler-Plates-Codeigniter-3.x-Login/blob/master/login.php)

**Step-8. The Controller**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Login_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function index()
{
    if($this->isLoggedin()){ redirect(base_url().'login/dashboard');}
    $data['title']='Login Boiler Plate';
    if($_POST)
    {
        $config=array(
            array(
                'field' => 'username',
                'label' => 'Username',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
            )
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            // if validation has errors, save those errors in variable and send it to view
            $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
        } else {
            // if validation passes, check for user credentials from database
            $user = $this->Login_model->checkUser($_POST);
            if ($user) {
            // if an record of user is returned from model, save it in session and send user to dashboard
                $this->session->set_userdata($user);
                redirect(base_url() . 'Login/dashboard');
            } else {
            // if nothing returns from model , show an error
                $data['errors'] = 'Sorry! The credentials you have provided are not correct';
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }

}
public function change_password()
{
    if($this->isLoggedin()){
        $data['title']='Change Password';
        if($_POST)
        {
            $config=array(
                array(
                    'field' => 'old_password',
                    'label' => 'Old Password',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required|callback_checkPassword'
                ),
                array(
                    'field' => 'password',
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
                ),
                array(
                    'field' => 'conf_password',
                    'label' => 'Confirm Password',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required|matches[password]'
                )
            );
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
            {
                // if validation has errors, save those errors in variable and send it to view
                $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
                $this->load->view('change_password',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                // if validation passes, check for user credentials from database
                $this->Login_model->updatePassword($_POST['password'],$this->session->userdata['id']);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('log_success','Congratulations! Password Changed');
                redirect(base_url() . 'Login/dashboard');
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('change_password',$data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        redirect(base_url().'Login');
    }

}

public function dashboard()
{
    if($this->isLoggedin())
    {
        $data['title']='Welcome! You are logged in';
        $this->load->view('success',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect(base_url().'Login');
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url().'Login');
}

public function isLoggedin()
{
    if(!empty($this->session->userdata['id']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

**Step-8. The Model**

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function checkUser($data)
{
    $st=$this->db->SELECT('*')->from('users')
                    ->WHERE('username',$data['username'])
                    ->WHERE('password',sha1(md5($data['password'])))
                    ->get()->result_array();
    if(count($st)>0)
    {
        return $st[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public function checkPassword($str)
{
    $st=$this->db->SELECT('*')->from('users')
        ->WHERE('id',$this->session->userdata['id'])
        ->WHERE('password',sha1(md5($str)))
        ->get()->result_array();
    if(count($st)>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public function updatePassword($password,$id)
{
    $pass=array(
        'password' => sha1(md5($password))
    );
    $this->db->WHERE('id',$id)->update('users',$pass);
}
}
```

**Step-9. Testing**

Open Database in Phpmyadmin and insert sample data in to your table using following query

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `fullname`, `status`) 
VALUES
(1, 'john', '56f5950b728849d0b97c1bccf1691c090ab6734c', 'John Vick', 
'approved');
```

Test-1
Empty Submit

---

[image]

It will produce the error, which we are storing in an errors index in Controller, passing it to view and displaying it in the view if the value exists.

Test-2. Wrong Credentials

### Provide any username and password (random)

[image]

Test-3. Correct Credentials

> Username: john 
>   Password: john

---

[image]

[Success View Source Code](https://github.com/malikmudassar/Boiler-Plates-Codeigniter-3.x-Login/blob/master/success.php)

**ALERTS!!**

This is a basic code for kick starters and there is a lot more room for improvements like [Security](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html) Features and [Encryption](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html)

**Complete Source Code**

You can download the complete source code from Git at [Boiler-Plates-Codeigniter-3.x-Login](https://github.com/malikmudassar/Boiler-Plates-Codeigniter-3.x-Login)