# Codeigniter Unable to load the requested file: upload_form.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

CodeIgniter *Unable to load the requested file: upload_form.php*

I am getting this type of An Error Was Encountered.

Here is my controller file that i am uploading.
**Controller**
Upload.php

```
   class Upload extends CI_Controller
```

{

```
  public function __construct()
  { 
     parent::__construct(); 
     $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); 
  }

  public function index()
        { 
     $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' )); 
  } 

  public function do_upload()
  { 
     $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png'; 
     $config['max_size']      = 100; 
     $config['max_width']     = 1024; 
     $config['max_height']    = 768;  
     $this->load->library('upload');
     $this->upload->initialize($config);

     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
     {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error); 
     }

     else
     { 
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data); 
     } 
  }
```

}

Here i am uploading my view file.
**View**
Upload_form.php

```
<?php echo $error; ?>
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload'); ?>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Tried doing a google search for this?

Comment: You question is too broad. There are too many possible answers. SO is not a discussion platform.

Comment: I edited this question because i am not able to ask new question before 3 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just Googled [Example for multi user role having Admin, user by using CodeIgniter](https://www.google.com/search?q=Example%20for%20multi%20user%20role%20having%20Admin%2C%20user%20by%20using%20CodeIgniter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and I got a good result set.

Then I noticed the below link which I got from the google result which is what you need.

http://www.w3programmers.com/making-multi-level-login-system-codeigniter/

Note: Please spend time on researching before posting to SO!!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1**

User Table

```
 ID  |  Name    | Email    | Password  | Role
 ==============================================
 1   |  abc     | abc@c.c  | ASDFAS    | user
 2   |  def     | def@c.c  | adfasdfsa | admin
```

**Step-2**

Login Controller

```
public function index()
{
    if($this->isLoggedin()){ redirect(base_url().'login/dashboard');}
    $data['title']='Login Boiler Plate';
    if($_POST)
    {
        $config=array(
            array(
                'field' => 'username',
                'label' => 'Username',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
            )
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            // if validation has errors, save those errors in variable and send it to view
            $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
            $data['csrf'] = array(
                'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
                'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
            );
            $data['title']='Login Boiler Plate';
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
        } else {
            // if validation passes, check for user credentials from database
            $data = $this->security->xss_clean($_POST);
            $user = $this->Login_model->checkUser($data);
            if ($user) {
            // if an record of user is returned from model, save it in session and send user to dashboard
                $this->session->set_userdata($user);

                redirect(base_url() . $user['role']);
            } else {
            // if nothing returns from model , show an error
                $data['errors'] = 'Sorry! The credentials you have provided are not correct';
                $data['csrf'] = array(
                    'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
                    'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
                );
                $data['title']='Login Boiler Plate';
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $data['csrf'] = array(
            'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
            'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
        );
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }

}
```

To see Model and forms start up Read [Codeigniter 3.x Login with Form Validation -Boiler plate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084899/codeigniter-3-x-login-with-form-validation-boiler-plate)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain one table for admin users with roles.according to roles you can fetch and display data or redirect to different pages as per your need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rename "Upload_form.php" to "upload_form.php"